# Additional <style> tag appearing breaking react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-engine](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine) with a layout that renders the whole HTML document and I'm getting an `Invariant Violation`  because of an empty style tag that is appearing in the server source.

My Layout looks like this: (Coffee Script)

```
render: ->
  React.DOM.html {},
    React.DOM.head {},
      React.DOM.title {}, (@props.pageTitle || @props.strings['site-title'])
      React.DOM.link {href: '/assets/bundle.css', rel: 'stylesheet'}
      React.DOM.link {href: '/assets/img/logo.png', rel: 'icon'}
    React.DOM.body {},
      HeaderStrip @props
      if @props.flash
        Flash @props.flash
      React.DOM.div {className: 'blocks'},
        SideBar {}
        React.DOM.div {className: 'mainContent'}, @props.children
      React.DOM.script {src: '/assets/bundle.js'}
```

The last element before `</head>` should be a link to the site icon but it is `<style type="text/css"></style>` when rendered by the server.

I assume that because there is no `data-reactid` this isn't a react issue but more likely a browser *bug* adding additional elements to `<head>`.

Can I stop react crashing on this particular `Invariant Violation` or add a tag to prevent the browser messing with the head tag?

Comment: *I assume that because there is no data-reactid this isn't a react issue but more likely a browser bug adding additional elements to `<head>`."* That seems like a **really** rash assumption. [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Yes, browsers have bugs sometimes, but adding elements to `head`. Nope.

Comment: A _bug_ introduced by the browser, most likely an extension but what ever is doing it it is adding something to the DOM React is not expecting to be there